# Laravel Factory State- Unable to locate factory

Tags: php, laravel, state, factory

I have a problem when executing the factory, i have used the factory state for factories but it will give me an error when i execute the factory
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#factory-states

I have this UserFactory.php which contains the code below.

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->state(App\User::class,'suggestor', function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'FirstName'=>$faker->firstName, 
        'LastName'=>$faker->lastName, 
        'Username'=>$faker->userName, 
        'password'=>bcrypt('123asd!@#'),
        'Email'=>$faker->email,
        'AccountType'=>0,
    ];
});
```

i am using **tinker** to execute the factory commands and tried different syntax but it really does not solve the problem.

```
>>> factory(User::class, 1)->states('suggestor')->make();
[!] Aliasing 'User' to 'App\User' for this Tinker session.
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unable to locate factory with name [default] [User].'
>>> factory(App\User::class, 1)->states('suggestor')->make();
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App/User].'
>>> factory(\App\User::class, 1)->states('suggestor')->make();
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App/User].'
>>> factory('App\User')->states('suggestor')->make();
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App/User].'
>>> factory('App\User',1)->states('suggestor')->make();
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App/User].'
>>>
```

i hope there's anyone out there can help me.

**Update:**
I have tried running it on database seed but i think it's still the same error.
but when i tried on the other model it seems fine. i think the problem is on the User model which comes out of the box by laravel and note that i haven't change anything on the user model except the model attributes.

error produce by seeder
[image]

Comment: try it in a seeder

Comment: i have tried running it in a seeder but the error is the same.. i have an update above for the error

Comment: Have you tried `'App\User'` instead of `App\User::class` ?

Comment: yes i have tried also but it wont work

Comment: i think I've got it now, we need to define first a factory for the User Model before we can set any states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you need a default factory. Please compare the following two:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
        'remember_token' => $faker->randomNumber(),
    ];
});

$factory->state(App\User::class, 'test_state', function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => 'Namoshek',
        'email' => 'namoshek@example.com',
    ];
});
```

The first definition is the default factory for users, when not giving a state. You can call them with `factory(App\User::class, 10)->create()` where `10` is optional to give the number of models to create.

You can also chain `->states('test_state')` after the call to `factory()`:
 `factory(App\User::class)->states('test_state')->create()`, which will first run the default factory and then apply the changes defined by the given state on the model. But you always need a default factory, otherwise the system doesn't know where and what to apply the state to.

By the way, there is a difference between `->create()` and `->make()`. The latter does only create the models without persisting them in the database, whereas the first one persists them. So `->create()` is equivalent to `->make()->save()`.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it also happens that factory works fine in web routes and tests but in tinker it behaves as it is mentioned above. In that case you can try to clear laravel application cache. here are the commmands.

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

this will clear all the caches. then i could create model instances using factory.

```
>>> factory(User::class)->create() // or
>>> factory(Book::class)->create()
```